# Column makes fonts smaller

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts, fonts, column

When you use `Column` (or `Grid`) a previously styled element with explicit font-size setting appears much smaller. Here is an example

```
cell = Framed[Style[(2*x^(3/2))/3, FontSize -> 14], 
   FrameMargins -> 10, 
   FrameStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], LightGray}, 
   RoundingRadius -> 3];
{cell, Column[{cell}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I looked through the options of `Column`, `Grid`, and `GridBox` but I couldn't find how I can prevent this when I output an expression with nested columns or grids. And setting the font-size larger, so that it appears to be non-scaled sounds like a bad idea.

Can anyone give me some insight?

## Update

With the help of Roman's answer, I could fix my layout. However, there seems to be a bug in `Panel` which does not respect the settings. Please compare the two usages of `Panel` without and with a *title*:

```
Column[{Item[cell, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]}]
Panel[Column[{Item[cell, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]}]]
Panel[Column[{Item[cell, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]}], "Hello"]
```

> [image: panel]

Three different font-sizes. I simply removed the `Panel` as it was not extremely important.

Comment: I guess it's like "display math" vs "inline math" in LaTeX but I can't recall the controlling option. In other words, it's the same thing that makes the fonts smaller in the denominator of a fraction.

Comment: @Szabolcs I only found `ScriptSizeMultipliers` but that's not it. `ImageSizeMultipliers` sounded good but I couldn't make it work.. hmmm. Waiting for Kuba :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an option for `Column` or `Grid` to avoid this: `AllowScriptLevelChange`

```
cell = Framed[Style[(2*x^(3/2))/3, FontSize -> 14], 
   FrameMargins -> 10, 
   FrameStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], LightGray}, 
   RoundingRadius -> 3];
{cell, Column[{cell}, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Honestly, I don't know why `Panel` doesn't respect `AllowScriptLevelChange`. As a workaround you can use `ScriptLevel -> 0` inside `Style` to fix the size of `Panel` with the title

```
cell2 = Framed[Style[(2*x^(3/2))/3, FontSize -> 14, ScriptLevel -> 0],
    FrameMargins -> 10, 
   FrameStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], LightGray}, 
   RoundingRadius -> 3];

Panel[Column[{Item[cell]}], "Hello"]
Panel[Column[{Item[cell2]}], "Hello"]
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh, that deserves a big upvote. Thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: It is completely beyond my imagination how on earth I should get this working with nested `Grid`, `Panel`, `Item`, ... Look at this `{cell, Panel[Column[{cell}, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]]}` and [here is the image for that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SlPCQ.png). Oh my..

Comment: @halirutan I'm not sure what result you're trying to achieve. Could you explain? or upload an image?

Comment: I simply kicked the `Panel` out, but if you are interested, you can have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Yep, strange. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 11):

Another approach is to set `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False` via `GridBoxOptions`:

```
{cell, Style[
  Panel[Column[{cell}], "Hello", DefaultBaseStyle -> None],
  GridBoxOptions -> {AllowScriptLevelChange -> False}]}
```

> [image: screenshot]

---

For curiosity, here is a low-level workaround based on `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False`:

```
{cell,
 RawBoxes@Replace[ToBoxes[
    Panel[Column[{cell}], "Hello", DefaultBaseStyle -> None]], 
   gb_GridBox :> 
    RuleCondition@Append[gb, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False], -1]}
```

> [image: output]

---

> Honestly, I don't know why `Panel` doesn't respect `AllowScriptLevelChange`.

Actually `PanelBox` doesn't change the `ScriptLevel`, but when labeled `Panel` is used, label is added by wrapping the contents of the panel by `GridBox` which doesn't inherit `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False` (what I would count as a **bug**) and hence changes the `ScriptLevel`. The same is true for `Labeled` and the same workaround works:

```
{cell, Labeled[cell, "Hello", Top],
 RawBoxes@Replace[ToBoxes[
    Labeled[cell, "Hello", Top]], 
   gb_GridBox :> RuleCondition@Append[gb, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False], -1]}
```

> [image: screenshot]