# FontSize of fraction after TableForm is small

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, cells, style, format

FontSize of fraction after applying `TableForm` is small.

```
{k1 + (y1 + y2)/(x1 + x2), k2 + (y2 + y3)/(x2 + x3), k3 + (y1 + y3)/(x1 + x3)} // TableForm
```

[image]

I want the font size of the fraction to be the same as before applying `TableForm`.

A workaround may be possible, like changing font size of numerator and denominator (and the middle horizontal bar, because it became thinner). But I believe there is a straight way to do this.

The answer can suggest a way not using `TableForm`.

My question is actually a special case of the general question :

*Can I arrange expressions the way I want (e.g. vertically, or table like,...) without any change of the size or shapes of expressions?*

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
After getting a comment : Thank you!

```
Grid[Transpose[{{k1 + (y1 + y2)/(x1 + x2), k2 + (y2 + y3)/(x2 + x3), 
    k3 + (y1 + y3)/(x1 + x3)}}],
 AllowScriptLevelChange -> False, Spacings -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fractions formatting in Column / Grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47746/fractions-formatting-in-column-grid) or [Column makes fonts smaller](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175451/column-makes-fonts-smaller/175466). Also search for `AllowScriptLevelChange` – there are many questions about this.

Comment: Thank you, I am reading it!

Comment: Would it be possible to say that using a `Grid` rather than a `TableForm` always gives us 
 more sophisticated control(more option, exact way)?