# Undoing Rubi's Subst

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

With sufficiently complicated integrands, Rubi often leaves integrals in the form

`Subst[Int[expr1, x], x, expr2]`

where x is the integration variable. I have been unable to find documentation for what Subst actually does: I assume it stands for a substitution of the form x->expr2, but I would like to 'undo' it, and to do that I would need to understand it better. Does it eg. mean that the substitution has already been made in expr1 (if not, my problem would basically be solved, since I could just get expr1 out of this form)?

What I'm after for is a function undoSubst such that, for expr3 for which Int[expr3,x] is of the form of Subst[...], I can call undoSubst[Subst[...]] and have it return expr3.

Comment: Could you give an actual example of an integral that gives rise to this output?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do as you did not give an example. It looks like parsing of Rubi ouput? this [recreational-challenge-best-looking-output-for-rubi-integration-steps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175188/recreational-challenge-best-looking-output-for-rubi-integration-steps) question has good info on Subst.  If you are looking for an internal function to modify Rubi's output may be you can ask at [Rubi forum](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#Rule-Based-Integration_Lobby:gitter.im) as the Author Albert Rich reads that. He might be able to help better on this.

Comment: If you run `??Subst` you will get at least a basic idea: "Subst[u,x,v] returns u with all nondummy occurrences of x replaced by v and resulting constant terms replaced by 0." You will also see the code for `Subst`, which might help.

Comment: @MarcoB here is an example showing Subst  `Steps[Int[Sin[x]/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]`  after loading `Rubi`. The steps with `Subst` on them are now displayed on the console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for being too vague --- I managed to reverse-engineer the behaviour of Subst enough by finding a sufficiently simple integrand for which the result involves a Subst and as such have an answer to my own question.

If intres is of the form Subs[Int[a,x],x,b], then

`(#[[1]][[1]] /. {#[[2]] -> #[[3]]})*(intres /. Thread[Variables@intres -> 1])*  D[#[[3]], #[[2]]] &[((intres)/(intres /. Thread[Variables@intres -> 1]))]`

appears to return the original integrand that can then be integrated numerically, which is what was my motivation for doing this.  I confirmed this numerically with the integrand ArcSin[Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[1 + x]].

Notably, this behaviour, eg the inclusion of the Jacobian factor, is *not* how I would have interpreted the result of Subst's ??-query posted in the comments.